# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been making an Auto Moderation bot recently. I made it that if the person has 30 warnings the person will be banned. But it's showing me an error instead. I tried to fix it myself but don't know what the problem is. Here is my code that i use:

```js
if (warns.warns.length === 30 && message.member.bannable) {
 embed.addField(
  `⛔ ${message.author.tag} has reached 30 warnings.`,
  `**${message.author} has been banned permanently.**`,
  true
 );
 setTimeout(function() {
  message.member
   .send(banemb)
   .then((message) => message.member.ban({ reason: '30 warnings' }));
 }, 1000);
}
```

And this is the error I got:

```
{
  "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ban' of null
at /app/app.js:157:51
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)"
}
```

Comment: `message.member` is null, which is why you can't call the function `ban()` on it.

Comment: The error means that `message.member` has the value `null`, not an object with a `ban` method. Read the documentation for this API again. You may have to test first whether `message.member` is `null` or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `.then(message =>` to `.then(msg =>`

Because you override the message variable so the new `message` variable is `null`

```js
setTimeout(function() {
 message.member
  .send(banemb)
  .then((msg) => message.member.ban({ reason: '30 warnings' }));
}, 1000);
```